# Autoit SetKeyboardLayout

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, autoit, keyboard-layout

I've been trying to get this autoit function to work:

```
_WinAPI_SetKeyboardLayout ( $hWnd, $iLanguage [, $iFlags = 0] )
```

I was just wondering what the $hWnd argument is supposed to be. In the documentation for this function it says: "Handle to the window to set input locale identifier."

This makes absolutely no sense to me, however I noticed that the second argument, $iLanguage is defined as "The input locale identifier." so They're definitely connected in that way.

Comment: Here is the docs for this function http://tinyurl.com/ocqttq8

Comment: Yeah that's the thing I was looking at - the documentation seems to be a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handle or hWnd is just a unique number every window has. You can get the window handle with [WinGetHandle("WINNAME")](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinGetHandle.htm)

Comment: Thanks that seems to work. One quick follow-up: is the keyboard layout switch local to the window it is run in?

Comment: The helpfile says " to the specified window" but just try it out.